# Angular auto complete returns a blank list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using AngularJS to create an auto complete. The list of values for auto completion will be provided using json. In my app, when I start typing, I get an empty list. All the values are blank. Here's my view code :

```
<md-autocomplete flex required
    md-input-name="un_registered[vehicle_attributes][brand_name]"
    md-no-cache="mainCtrl.noCache"
    md-selected-item-chang=""
    md-search-text-change=""
    md-selected-item="mainCtrl.selectedItem"
    md-search-text="mainCtrl.searchText"
    md-items="item in mainCtrl.querySearch(mainCtrl.searchText)"
    md-item-text="item.display"
    md-floating-label="Brand" id="un_registered_vehicle_attributes_brand_name">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="mainCtrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
  <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
    <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite state.</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
  </div>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Here's my `querySearch` function :

```
mainCtrl.querySearch = querySearch;

function querySearch(query) {
    return $http.get("/panel/all_brands.json")
        .then(function(result) {
            return result;
        });
}
```

My json data :

```
["Example Brand","abcdd","Example Brand2Hh","rr","ffff"]
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: It's a promisse issue, you are returning nothing from your method.

Comment: @Fals Im a bit new to Angular... how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 1:

```
 function querySearch(query) {
    $http.get("/panel/all_brands.json").success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        mainCtrl.TestData = data;
    });
}
```

Change 2:

```
md-search-text-change="mainCtrl.querySearch(mainCtrl.searchText)"
md-selected-item="mainCtrl.selectedItem"
md-search-text="mainCtrl.searchText"
md-items="item in mainCtrl.TestData | filter: mainCtrl.searchText"
```

Change 3:

```
 <span md-highlight-text="mainCtrl.searchText">{{item}}</span>
```

Comment: I edited the function. But now nothing happens. Not even an empty list :-(

Comment: Is your GET returning a 200 response? As in success?

Comment: 300s are redirects. You aren't getting data back is most likely the root cause here.

Comment: Hmmm when i manually visit the url I can see the correct json data. What might be the problem?

Comment: I added a console.log before the return to print the `data`. It gave me this `Object {data: Array[5], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: Array[5]headers: (name) {status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object`

Comment: Thats good. Try making the changes in my answer and see what you get on the page itself. I eddited it.

Comment: Thanks for the help :-). I did that and got the output : `["Example Brand","abcdd","Example Brand2Hh","rr","ffff"]` but still the auto complete is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82828/discussion-between-kreepn-and-eapubs).